# pip3 install couchdbkit failed with "Command "python setup.py egg_info"

Tags: python, couchdbkit

I am unable to install couchdbkit in ubuntu. The command: `pip3 install couchdbkit` gives this following error:

```
Collecting couchdbkit
  Using cached couchdbkit-0.6.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-_302m_0e/couchdbkit/setup.py", line 25, in <module>
        long_description = file(
    NameError: name 'file' is not defined

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_302m_0e/couchdbkit/
```

Please guide me if there any other way to install couchdbkit in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because couchdbkit is not supported in python3. `file` was removed in versions 3x from python. This is also indicated  [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/couchdbkit):

> Couchdbkit requires Python 2.x superior to 2.6.

Why pip3 still tries to download it is another issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply